# “PTY allocation request failed on channel 2” while using SSH

Tags: macos, ssh

These days when I try to SSH to my server I get this error:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 2
```

I used to SSH to that server for about 2 years.

What happened to my OS (OS X lion) this week that caused this problem?

log file for : ssh -vvv user@X.X.X.X

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to X.X.X.X [X.X.X.X] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/AR/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/AR/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/AR/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/AR/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 131/256
debug2: bits set: 532/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host X.X.X.X filename /Users/AR/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host X.X.X.X filename /Users/AR/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'X.X.X.X' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/AR/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 506/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/AR/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/AR/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/AR/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/AR/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/AR/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/AR/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
USER@X.X.X.X's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 61 padlen 19 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to X.X.X.X ([X.X.X.X]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env COMMAND_MODE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: Are you using the ssh client out of the box or did you install your own? Did it ever work with Lion?

Comment: I use default ssh client, yes it work on lion at first.

Comment: WIld guess: How do the permissions on /dev/pty* look like (especially /dev/ptyp2)? Should be crw-rw-rw-

Comment: @patrix Yes the permission is crw-rw-rw-

Comment: Can you confirm this doesn't happen from another client computer?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Did you check permissions both on the client and the server?

Comment: Can you please run ssh with `-vvv` and sshd with config DEBUG3 and then include both logs into the question?

Comment: @MattiSchneider-Ghibaudo Other client can connect to server

Comment: @patrix I add log file for ssh with -vvv

Comment: Have you tried Repair disk permission, and if it sill fails following http://forums.quantact.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=1149 ?

Comment: @Gio Yes I did, I think my server has problem and I must not change any settings in my OS X

Comment: Is the server running OSX?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that problem still exists, but asking The-Big-G gave the impression that you may have a problem with the mounting of the PTS filesystem in /etc/fstab on the server:

[pty allocation request failed - 1st](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0-a-676673/)

[pty allocation request failed - 2nd](https://wuhai.wordpress.com/2009/06/06/ssh-connection-hang-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0/)

[pty allocation request failed - 3rd](http://blog.asteriosk.gr/2009/02/20/pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0/)

I checked about four answers and the all say the same : a problem with /dev/pts on the server

Of course in theorie nobody should be able to connect. But after all it's computers and often no logic is involved :)